# Dynamic loading of JavaScript code / file in an Electron application

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Is it possible to load an external JavaScript code / file on startup of an Electron application?

I have tried it with "runInthisContext" and `run` of the `module` `vm2`, but "require" in the external file seems not to be working, because the module will not be found.

The Electron application is packaged in an `app.asar` file and some files are unpacked:

Content of the file from app.asar:

[image: Content of the file from app.asar]

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const  {NodeVM} = require('vm2');

var data = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../app.asar.unpacked/local_orchestrator_ext.js'));

const vm = new NodeVM({
   consle: 'inherit',
   sandbox: {},
   require: {
      external: true,
      builtin: ['*']
   }
});

vm.run(data, 'local_orchestrator_ext.js');
```

Content of the unpacked file:

[image: Content of the unpacked file]

```
const {net} = require('electron');
const got = require('got');
const fs = require('fs');
```

Error on startup:

[image: Error on startup]

```
[Main Instruction]
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process

[Content]
Uncaught Exception:
VMError: Cannot find module 'electron'
    at _require (D:\Users\l001263\AppData\Local\AvcFrontendClient\app-1.3.223\resources\app.asar\node_modules\vm2\lib/sandbox.js:295:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Users\l001263\AppData\Local\AvcFrontendClient\app-1.3.223\local_orchestrator_ext.js:1:77)
    at NodeVM.run (D:\Users\l001263\AppData\Local\AvcFrontendClient\app-1.3.223\resources\app.asar\node_modules\vm2\lib\main.js:520:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Users\l001263\AppData\Local\AvcFrontendClient\app-1.3.223\resources\app.asar\local_orchestrator.js:17:4)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Users\l001263\AppData\Local\AvcFrontendClient\app-1.3.223\resources\app.asar\local_orchestrator.js:18:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:693:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:704:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:602:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:541:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:533:3)
```

Comment: try to install electron using `npm i electron`

Comment: ? the electron app works already
only the external code doesn't find the module

Comment: Instead of screenshots, it would be better to have both the code and the error information as text (so potential answerers and search engines can find it).

Comment: ok, done

regards 
Klaus